# Custom annotation for null into Kotlin JVM

Tags: java, kotlin, null, annotations

**My goal**: writing a custom field annotation that throws an exception if null is set to a nullable variable.

```
data class Contact (
    @RequiredAttribute
    var name: String?,
    var number: String?
)
```

So if I do something like `val contact = Contact(null, "test")` it should end up with an exception with a message like `Attribute name can't be set as null.`

**My question**: is this possible to achieve? I never wrote a custom annotation in Java or Kotlin, so I'm quite noob on this field.

**EDIT 2nd question**: is it possible to check if an object has some annotated attributes that are null and then throw an exception?

Comment: Rather than an annotation, I would say write a Delegate.

Comment: @Enzokie the purpose of this is just learning, not something cool in production. Since I never wrote an annotation, It could be something like a "Hello World!" example.

Comment: Annotations cannot have any behaviour themselves.

Comment: If I am not mistaken you can't normally initialize the contact class via this `val contact = Contact(null, "test")` if you want to make your annotation works at runtime. You probably need to use the reflection *ceremony* e.g. like this > `val context = factory.create(Contact::class).args(....).create()`

Answer (score 0):

Kotlin already has a property delegate for this:

```
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

var name: String by Delegates.notNull()
```

And the docs:

```
/**
 * Returns a property delegate for a read/write property with a non-`null` value that is initialized not during
 * object construction time but at a later time. Trying to read the property before the initial value has been
 * assigned results in an exception.
 *
 * @sample samples.properties.Delegates.notNullDelegate
 */
public fun <T: Any> notNull(): ReadWriteProperty<Any?, T> = NotNullVar()
```

I'd suggest using [property delegates](http://the-cogitator.com/2018/09/29/by-the-way-exploring-delegation-in-kotlin.html#property-delegation) when you achieve something like this: it is the idiomatic way to do so and property delegates were added for this purpose.

If you really want to allow `null`s in your Kotlin program, you can also do annotation processing with `kapt`. More info about this [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/kapt.html).

Comment: As documentation is saying `Returns a property delegate for a read/write property with a non-null value that is initialized not during object construction time but at a later time.`. I'm using a data class and, as far as I know, those does not support delegates.

Comment: Oh you didn't state that in your question. Then you are out of luck since `lateinit` doesn't work either. I think it is a design flaw if you allow `null` into a Kotlin program though. I edited my answer.

Comment: I don't think that's a design flaw if Kotlin is not used by 100% of the developer community, but by the way my question was pretty clear with the use of the data class, and a solution at creation time. Look at the code snippet.